# GraphQL endpoint return null object in Nest.js

Tags: graphql, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I'm using Nest.js and Sequelize-Typescript to build a GraphQL API.

When I called delete and update mutations I got a null object, but the operation it is done. I need to put {nullable: true} because I got a error saying `Cannot return null for non-nullable field` . How I fix it? I need the endpoint to return the updated object to show the information on the front

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtARe.png)

*book.dto.ts*

```
import { ObjectType, Field, Int, ID } from 'type-graphql';

@ObjectType()
export class BookType {
    @Field(() => ID, {nullable: true})
    readonly id: number;
    @Field({nullable: true})
    readonly title: string;
    @Field({nullable: true})
    readonly author: string;
}
```

*book.resolver.ts*

```
import {Args, Mutation, Query, Resolver} from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Book } from './model/book.entity';
import { BookType } from './dto/book.dto';
import { CreateBookInput } from './input/createBook.input';
import { UpdateBookInput } from './input/updateBook.input';
import { BookService } from './book.service';

@Resolver('Book')
export class BookResolver {
    constructor(private readonly bookService: BookService) {}

    @Query(() => [BookType])
    async getAll(): Promise<BookType[]> {
        return await this.bookService.findAll();
    }

    @Query(() => BookType)
    async getOne(@Args('id') id: number) {
        return await this.bookService.find(id);
    }

    @Mutation(() => BookType)
    async createItem(@Args('input') input: CreateBookInput): Promise<Book> {
        const book = new Book();
        book.author = input.author;
        book.title = input.title;
        return await this.bookService.create(book);
    }

    @Mutation(() => BookType)
    async updateItem(
        @Args('input') input: UpdateBookInput): Promise<[number, Book[]]> {
        return await this.bookService.update(input);
    }

    @Mutation(() => BookType)
    async deleteItem(@Args('id') id: number) {
        return await this.bookService.delete(id);
    }

    @Query(() => String)
    async hello() {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

*book.service.ts*

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {InjectRepository} from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import {Book} from './model/book.entity';
import {DeleteResult, InsertResult, Repository, UpdateResult} from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class BookService {
    constructor(@Inject('BOOKS_REPOSITORY') private readonly bookRepository: typeof Book) {}

    findAll(): Promise<Book[]> {
        return this.bookRepository.findAll<Book>();
    }

    find(id): Promise<Book> {
       return this.bookRepository.findOne({where: {id}});
    }

    create(data): Promise<Book> {
        return data.save();
    }

    update(data): Promise<[number, Book[]]> {
        return this.bookRepository.update<Book>(data, { where: {id: data.id} });
    }

    delete(id): Promise<number> {
        return this.bookRepository.destroy({where: {id}});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to return those fields from a delete? You must already have them on your front end... you could just change the return type of that mutation to true or false based on whether it worked or not...  and in the update you could do the mutation and add returning: true in your options if you are using postgres... if not then don't return the result of the update, do the update and return the result of findOne or findById whichever is applicable

Answer (score 11):

You can fix it setting option parameter in the resolver query

```
@Query(() => BookType, { nullable: true })
```